# Flow between two infinite plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, steady-state

I recently got set this problem and I was wondering if anyone would be able to give me some hints/intuition on how to solve it. Thanks.

An incompressible thermal conducting fluid is contained between two infinite horizontal plates separated by a distance $H$. Initially the plates and fluid are at rest at temperature $T_0$. At time $t = 0$ the upper plate is raised to temperature $T_1 > T_0$ and moved horizontally at speed $U$.

Q. Assuming the fluid flow is laminar, how can I show that the velocity and temperature field equations reduce to:
$$v=p=0$$
$$\rho u_t(y,t)=\mu u_{yy}(y,t)$$
$$\rho cT_t(y,t)=kT_{yy}(y,t) + \mu (u_y(y,t))^2$$

A. Firstly, I used the momentum equation, to get:
$$\rho(u_{t} +uu_{x} + vu_{y})=-p_{x} + \mu(u_{xx}+u_{yy})$$
and:
$$\rho(v_{t} +uv_{x} + vv_{y})=-p_{y} + \mu(v_{xx}+v_{yy})$$.

Since the flow is laminar are we allowed to assume that $v=0$? In which case, the second equation gives, $-p_{y}=0$,  so $p$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ only.

Also are we allowed to assume $u_x +v_{y} =0$? As this then implies that $u_x =0$, so $u$ is a function of $y$ and $t$ only. 
However I am stuck at this point, so any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's just the velocity in the y-direction

Comment: Check out the site's homework policy.  Try to ask about a specific physics concept.

Comment: A five question question is always "wrong" on this site. Please reduce what you are asking to a very specific (single) conceptual question - especially in light of the homework policy.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @jackwo - you can improve your question by: 1. rewording your questions to specific issues and 2. showing what you have done so far to solve your problem.